# Get message_id from Telegram message - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem concerning a Telegram bot I am currently working on. I get messages from users in the following format:

```
   update { update_id: 82618016,
   message:
    { message_id: 363,
      from: { id: 22303518, first_name: 'Steve', language_code: 'de-DE' },
      chat: { id: 22303518, first_name: 'Steve', type: 'private' },
      date: 1501501753,
      text: 'j' } }
```

When I want to access the id of the chat I can do this without any problems by using

```
$.message.chat.id
```

As soon as a want to get the message_id or first_name I only get "undefined".

```
$.message.chat.first_name

$.message.message_id
```

Can anyone help me here? As far as I see it I understood the structure of the message correctly so I don't really know what's the problem here.

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: I am adding a bit more of my code here:

The main code for the bot (including the webhook) is this:

```
initializeBot();

function initializeBot(){

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
const PingController = require('./controllers/ping');
const OtherwiseController = require('./controllers/otherwise');

const tg = new Telegram.Telegram('MY_TOKEN_IS_HERE', {
    webhook: {
        url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com',
        port: process.env.PORT || 443,
        host: '0.0.0.0'
    }
})

tg.router.when(new Telegram.TextCommand('/ping', 'pingCommand'), new PingController())
    .otherwise (new OtherwiseController());

}
```

When the OtherwiseController gets called the following code is called (I reduced it to the essentials to clarify the problem.

```
class OtherwiseController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    handle($){

      console.log($.message.chat.first_name);
      console.log($.message.text);
      console.log($.message.chat.id);
      console.log($.message.message_id);        

    }
}
```

The console output for this message

```
update { update_id: 82618020,
   message:
    { message_id: 371,
      from: { id: 22303518, first_name: 'Steve', language_code: 'de-DE' },
      chat: { id: 22303518, first_name: 'Steve', type: 'private' },
      date: 1501509762,
      text: 'hello' } }
```

would be:

```
undefined
hello
22303518
undefined
```

Comment: would you please share a bit more of your code?

Comment: @tashakori I added code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to access properties this way: $.message.chat["first_name"]

Comment: @tashakori I just tried it but it still remains "undefined".
To find out more about which elements work and which don't, I just tried console.log($.message.date); which also works for some reason (returns the correct date from the message).

EDIT: I have an idea. Only the elements with an underscore don't work. Might I need to escape them?

Comment: I tried further elements like $.message.chat.type and it also works. I think more and more that it has something to do with the underscore. (that's the only thing the non-working elements have in common).

I tried this `console.log($.message.chat["first\_name"]);` though which didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: yea it's the underscore which has a problem, that's why i said if you have tried that way.
1.try to use double back slash with underscore
2.check the keys of the json object: Object.keys($.message.chat);

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

By using the Object.keys function I was able to determine that the key was for example "$.message.messageId" instead of message_id. 

I am quite new to stackoverflow: Can you add this as an answer or should I answer it myself and mark it as answer?

Comment: I added the answer, please accept and +1 it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below method to extract the keys of your json object, then you can access with an appropriate key:

```
Object.keys($.message.chat);
```